# How to use navigator buttons to execute actions other than navigate between pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app

Suppose I have the following snippet for an application using Onsenui:

```
<ons-navigator-toolbar title=""
    left-button-icon="fa fa-lg fa-edit"
    on-left-button-click="window.alert('asdf');"
    right-button-icon="fa fa-lg fa-plus"
    on-right-button-click="myAngularFunction();">
</ons-navigator-toolbar>
```

The functions for the events `on-left-button-click` and `on-right-button-click` are not getting called. Just functions to navigate between pages work (for instance, `ons.screen.presentPage('other_page.html')`).

Is this a known Onsenui limitation, a design principle or just a bug? Is there any way to overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's AngularJS limitation.

You cannot call function outside AngularJS.

you can wrap window.alert function inside your controller function.

Also, you need to set your controller above ons-navigator.

If you use, ons-navigator-toolbar, its scope is not the page but the navigator scope. This is current limitation of Onsen UI, it is being resolved in the next version.